# CS0234: Mvc does not exist in the System.Web namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I converted a ASP.net 4 webform project to Asp.net MVC4 according to Chapter 13 of the Professional ASP.NET 3.5 MVC, by Scott Hanselmen, Phil Haack, and Rob Conery, Published by Wiley Publishing, Inc. (ISBN: 978-0-470-38461-9).  I also followed this [blog](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/05/convert-web-forms-mvc3-how-to.html).  Now I can add Controllers, Views, etc. All the references are set properly. No build errors.  But upon launching the converted project, I got compilation errors.  I have mvc3 installed on the same machine. I even changed the reference to that. It still complain.  Could you help?  Thanks.

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 109:            <namespaces>
Line 110:                <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
Line 111:                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
Line 112:                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
Line 113:                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/> 

Source File: c:\Users\Jon\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CMT\Apps\Branches\3.0\Web.config    Line: 111
```

Comment: without reading the article, id like to know, did u add references to mvc dll's?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem can happen when you deploy your web application to a server, so you must check if you already installed MVC3.

Check if the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3` exists.

If it doesn't exist, you need to install it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491

---

If you wont to install you can add all DLLs locally in bin folder and add references to them this work fine if you host on server don't deploy ASP.NET Web Pages or MVC3.

Comment: Thanks!  And same story when it's MVC2: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=22079

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me too but in my case, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2 was missing. Installed MVC 2 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22079

Answer (score 89):

I had the same problem and I had solved it with:

1.Right click to solution and click `'Clean Solution'`

2.Click `'References'` folder in solution explorer and select the problem reference (in your case it seems System.Web.Mvc) and then right click and click `'Properties'`.

3.In the properties window, make sure that the `'Copy Local'` property is set to `'True'`

This worked for me. Hope it works for someone else

**Helpful Note**: As it has mentioned in comments by @Vlad:

If it is already set to True:

1. Set it False
2. Set it True again
3. Rebuild

Comment: In my case it was set to Copy Local = true but for some reason DLL wasn't there. I just set it to false and back to true > rebuild. Helped.

Comment: But... why do you have to do this? I just created an empty mvc project (vs 2013), and had to do this to get it to work. it means that by default, projects that you start in visual studio do not work. How could this slip by?

Comment: While using RedGate Ants Profiler, I got the System.Web.Mvc error; your solution solved the issue. Very strange since building the app without Ants was fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Check your runtime tag inside the web.config, and verify you have something like this declared:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
.....
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 7):

add Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc nuget package.

Answer (score 6):

I tried all these answers, even closed Visual Studio and deleted all bin directories.

After starting it up again the MVC reference appeared to have a yellow exclamation mark on it, so I removed it and added it again.

Now it works, without copy local.

Comment: Same case here! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

None of previous answers worked for me.

I noticed that my project was referencing another project using the `System.Web.Mvc` reference from the .NET Framework.

I just deleted that assembly and added the "[Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/)" NuGet package and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the reference to the assembly System.Web.Mvc in you project.

you may not have the System.Web.Mvc in your  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

So you need to add it and then to include it as reference to your projrect

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but all the applications in IIS were broken when they had been working previously.  None of the marked solutions helped me.  The problem ended up being an extra copy of web.config had been introduced to my root directory.  I removed that file and problem solved.