# CS0234: Missing Assembly Reference

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, configuration, assemblies

I have some missing assemblies in my PC, and don't have any idea how to fix it.

When I create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 internet application from template (using VS 2012) everything works fine. As soon as I try to integrate Web API controller I get a missing assembly reference error. For example, when I create application using ASP.NET 4 Web API default template and click "API" on the interface I get Compilation error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Description' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have checked the assembly and everything seems to be fine. It's in version 4.0. I have .NET framework 4.5  installed on my PC. Where should I look for the reason of the issue?

Comment: Try to follow [these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26391511/997668)

Comment: Your solution worked, I've set System.Web.Http copy local to 'true' and everything works fine. What does it mean though? Didn't have to do it on a different PC

Comment: You can [read about 'Copy Local' here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx). I would assume (and note this is only my assumption), you don't have `System.Web.Http.dll` installed in `GAC`.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I had something similar, and ended here with my googling so: I was referencing another project, the solution was building fine, but when I went to publish I got the CS0234 error. I resolved it by removing and re-adding the reference to the project. Hope this helps another random nomad some day.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this same error code (different missing reference) when compiling a PCL using msbuild but not when building via Visual Studio:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

In my case it was caused by a 'using Windows.Storage;' statement that was not actually referenced by any code in the file.  I removed the line and the error was fixed.