# Visual Studio Online build fails - Local works

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, continuous-integration, nuget

I upgraded to VS2015, and MVC was updated to 5.0.

I am able to build successfully on my local PC, but when I checkin to Visual Studio Online, and my CI build builds, it fails:

"The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I've used nuget manager to remove, and re-install MVC on my project - same results.

Looking at my references in the project, all looks OK.

[image]

I also notice in the log before the error happens:

```
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes 5.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes 5.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
```

But it seems when it builds, it doesn't know what MVC is. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked in the packages folder containing NuGet DLLs? NuGet package restore is notoriously unreliable. If you source control the DLLs you might avoid the build server having to restore the packages from NuGet

Comment: @GlenThomas - There is a packages folder that gets checked in. However, it only has a single file in the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3 folder within 'packages', called 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3.nupkg'. I'm not sure where the DLL is. If I 'Add items to folder', there is a Lib folder with the xml and dll file. Should those be added?

Comment: Go for it. It will save the build server having to try and download the packages, which often has its problems.

Comment: Tried it, but still fails. Seems it can't find the dll on TFS Online, but finds it locally.

Comment: You still have the same error? The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Comment: Yeah, @GlenThomas, same error. I'll try search for clues in the logs.

Comment: @Craig Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late to the game here, but I was having a very similar issue: Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'blank' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

This was building locally but not in VSTS. My solution was to delete the reference under the project's references, and then just add it back in again. The reference was to a namespace in a local project to the solution. For some reason it was being found locally but not found when checked into and built on VSTS.

Deleting the reference and then re-adding it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version number mentioned in all web.config files. I mean also those in the view folders; that they match the version 5.2.3.0

Comment: It builds locally though. Web.Config says"<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />" And 5.2.3.0 mentioned in the Views config file as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071392/the-type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc

Suggests cleaning the solution. I also recommend physically deleting the bin folder and then rebuilding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26391511/511438 suggests reseting the copy local flag too.

Answer (score 0):

Scan all your references and ensure, that all of them related to MVC have `Copy Local` property set `true`. Not only Mvc one.

Comment: Ah, so all references should be set to True? 'System' and all of those too?

Comment: @Craig oh, I meant, "related to MVC" - starting with System.Web.
updated my answer

Comment: @Craig yes, I had the same problem

Comment: Now I get: Global.asax.cs(5,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ... I checked System.Web, and 'Copy Local' is true.

Comment: @Craig bad news... Check also System.Net.*, WebGrease.* (if you have), WebMatrix.* (if you have). Check all external libs (referenced by nuget)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing all the folders within my Packages folder, leaving only repositories.config. This forces VSOnline to restore all the packages on each build.