# VSO continuous integration and custom DLL

Tags: git, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up CI with with visual studio online in an existing project, using git.

My project contains a custom DLL and I can not find a way to resolve this error :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1819): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "CaradbaAccess". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
>
> Models\Search\DbSearchResultsTests.cs (4): The type or namespace name
> 'CaradbaAccess' could not be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?)

Actually this file is contained (and also referenced) in the project and in the git repo.
Obviously this build on my machine.

Where do I have to put this file to make VSO build working?

Note :
This seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951990/visual-studio-online-build-fails-local-works) but it is not. The question in the link is about a nuget package, my problem is about a custom DLL.

Comment: Did you queue a build vNext or XAML build?

Comment: If you open your .*proj file and find the reference to 'CaradbaAccess' there should be a 'HintPath' associated with that reference. Is the HintPath relative or absolute?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to add this custom DLL to source control, and reference this DLL to your project, check in your whole solution and queue a build, VSO is supposed to find this DLL.

Comment: This dll is contained in the project and in the git repo.

Comment: Did you reference the dll from the source-controlled one?

Comment: Yes, it is referenced

Comment: Did you try to remove this dll and re-push it?